# I tried to assign values to structure variable via function in C

Tags: c, struct

I tried to assign values to structure variable via function in C. Is it possible assign values via function to struct variables? Or not help me to get correct answer.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Docinfo{
    int docNo;
    char docName[20];
    float charge;
}doc;

void store(doc doc1){
    doc1.docNo=123;
    strcpy(doc1.docName,"Jhon");
    doc1.charge=1500;
}

void display(doc doc1){
    printf("Doctor No: %d\nDoctor Name: %s\nDoctor Charge: %f\n",doc1.docNo,doc1.docName,doc1.charge);
}

int main(){
    doc doc1;

    store(doc1);
    display(doc1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
Doctor No: 4201168
Doctor Name: P a
Doctor Charge: 0.000000

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to pass the address of your variable to your function. Otherwise only a local copy is modified inside your functions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass by address, otherwise it just make a copy of `doc`:

```c
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Docinfo{
    int docNo;
    char docName[20];
    float charge;
}doc;

void store(doc *doc1){
    /* doc1 is now a pointer, so use -> instead of . */
    doc1->docNo=123;
    strcpy(doc1->docName,"Jhon");
    doc1->charge=1500;
}

void display(doc doc1){
    printf("Doctor No: %d\nDoctor Name: %s\nDoctor Charge: %f\n",doc1.docNo,doc1.docName,doc1.charge);
}

int main(){
    doc doc1;

    store(&doc1);
    display(doc1);

    return 0;
}
```